# Open Graph namespace declaration and Accelerated Mobile Page (AMP) Validation

Tags: facebook-opengraph, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I'm updating my site to AMP but by the time I try to [validate](https://search.google.com/search-console/amp) I get the following error:

> The attribute 'prefix' may not appear in tag 'head'

[image: AMP validation]

And the OG namespace declaration uses prefix, how can I workaround this issue?

Comment: In AMP most of the attributes are prohibited , reference link is
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec
If you are using og tags for implementing social share icons then check this sample example 
https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-social-share/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook sharing doesn't require the prefix attribute. So an easy workaround is to simply omit the prefix attribute. This is how ampbyexample.com does it and it still works:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com

Nevertheless, the AMP validator should support the prefix attribute. I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6852).

Comment: Actually, I tested the page on the OG debugging tool, and it works as expected, I was just wondering if removing the prefix attribute is going to be the right path, thanks for the heads up.